# Java - wait() and notifyAll()

Tags: java, multithreading

I've been looking some tutorials on the synchronization of multiple threads and communication via wait() and notifyAll() for solving this, but they didn't help me. Supposedly, my program launches 50 threads which check for available positions in an array, and get into waiting mode if there is none. When they end, notifyAll() resumes them, so they can look for free positions. However, this is resulting in various instances of IllegalMonitorStateException.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        Random rnd = new Random(new Date().getTime());
        boolean entrado = false;
        int i = 0;
        sm.acquire();
        synchronized (biblioteca) {
            System.out.println("Usuario " + id + " entra");
            while (!entrado) {
                for (i = 0; i < biblioteca.ordenadores.length && !entrado; i++) {
                    if (biblioteca.ordenadores[i] == 0) {
                        entrado = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!entrado) {
                    System.out.println("Usuario " + id + " en la sala de espera");
                    wait();
                }
            }

            biblioteca.ordenadores[i] = id;
            System.out.println("Usuario " + id + " ocupa Ordenador " + i
                    + "\nOrdenadores: " + biblioteca.muestraOrdenadores());
        }
        Thread.sleep(rnd.nextInt(2000));
        synchronized (biblioteca) {
            System.out.println("Usuario " + id + " termina de usar el Ordenador " + i + " y sale");
            biblioteca.ordenadores[i] = 0;
            notifyAll();
        }
        sm.release();

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: What is `sm`? Which line is throwing `IllegalMonitorStateException`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `wait()` and `notifyAll()` of `this` and you are synchronizing on `biblioteca`. You should call `biblioteca.wait()` and `biblioteca.notifyAll()`.

Comment: Then, other option would be setting synchronized methods in Biblioteca and call wait() and notifyAll() there, if I am correct. Anyways, problem solved.

Thank you very much, sir.

Answer (score 0):

According to the JavaDoc, IllegalMonitorStateException is thrown "to indicate that a thread has attempted to wait on an object's monitor or to notify other threads waiting on an object's monitor without owning the specified monitor."

As explained in [How do wait and notify really work?](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=98786) , in order to call foo.wait() or foo.notify(), the calling thread must own a lock on object foo. This exception is thrown if you call it without a preceding synchronized (foo) {.

Source: http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=128732